# Localstack create SNS topic for java integration test

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-integration, localstack

I am writing an integration test where I use stack to spin up a localstack docker container mocking AWS services.

This code will spin up the docker container

```
@RunWith(LocalstackTestRunner.class)
@LocalstackDockerProperties(services = {"dynamodb", "sns"})
```

Then i call a publisher from my applilcation from within one of my tests. But i get a topic not found exception

```
com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.NotFoundException: Topic does not exist (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NotFound; Request ID: 06c6a626)
```

I can't seem to find a good example of creating the SNS topic for the unit test with java online. I can find a command for the aws CLI that would create it something like this

```
$ aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4575 sns create-topic --name my_topic
```

But I am looking for something I can use inside my spring boot unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AmazonSNS amazonSNS = DockerTestUtils.getClientSNS();
amazonSNS.createTopic("testTopic");
```

In the `@Before` or in the beginning of your test.